# Trying to update ADT

Tags: android, adt

I am using ADT(Android Developing Tool) v22.3.0. It's an old version and the latest one is ADT v23.0.3. Whenever I click on check for updates it says "No updates were found". What should i do?

I'm using
Windows 8 64bit

Comment: Open Android Sdk Manager on Windows tab than Tool There u can update Your Adt

Comment: Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
Click Add, in the top-right corner.
In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: Now I'm getting an error message with "conflicting dependency"

Answer (score 0):

To update your ADT in your eclipse follow below steps:

1)  **Goto Help menu>Install New Software**
2)  It will popup new window in that click on **Add** Button in top-right corner
3)  On click of button it will show you one dialog in which you need to specify the url of ADT Plugins which is `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/` And add the name of your plugin as **ADT**
4)  After that it will show you all updates to be install.   Complete all the steps to install latest ADT.

Comment: I followed these steps but it says "Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency."

Comment: Try to download the ADT bundle archieve. `win64: http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702.zip` As you have old plugins already installed that is why its conflicting.

Comment: You are getting this error because there is a conflicting dependency somewhere. When you check for updates, Eclipse will check all plugins and features you have installed in the past. Try to update one thing at a time to identify which update has a conflicting dependency.